# Is there a way to use external font files with unicode-math?

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, ebgaramond

I use `fontspec` with LuaLaTeX to load fonts from external file even if they are not installed on the system. Such as

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=fonts/,
             Extension=.otf,
             UprightFont=*-Regular,
             ItalicFont=*-Italic,
             BoldFont=*-Bold,
             SmallCapsFont=*-AllSC,]{EBGaramond12}
```

I also use `unicode-math`, because it's awesome, usually with XITS Maths for the operators and numbers and EB Garamond for the letters.

```
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathbfsfit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin}]{EB Garamond}
```

Is there a way to combine these packages to use the letters from the local EB Garamond instead of the system's one?

Comment: All `fontspec` options are valid for `unicode-math` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@Khaled Hosny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94859/is-there-a-way-to-use-external-font-files-with-unicode-math#comment203134_94859), I have found out how to do it. It is not exactly true that all `fontspec` options are available for `unicode-math`. In this case, `unicode-math` doesn't seem to support the wildcard expansion feature of `fontspec`, so instead of

```
\setmathfont[
    range=\mathbfsfit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin}
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold]{EBGaramond12}
```

one has to use

```
 \setmathfont[
    range=\mathbfsfit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin},
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.otf,
    ItalicFont=EBGaramond12-Italic,
    BoldFont=EBGaramond12-Bold]{EBGaramond12-Regular}
```